# How do I save Test Cases in different Source Files in RIDE Robot Framework?

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

As mentioned in the question all of the test cases that we create a being saved in the same source file and we are having trouble checking in the code among our team with a lot of merge clashes. How do I save different test cases in different source files in RIDE?

Answer (score 0):

On the menubar, select "File" and then "New Project". RIDE uses the word "Project" to mean "test suite". Make sure the type is set to "File", give it a name, and click on the "Ok" button.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to work with some kind of source repository, and no constraint to strict to RIDE tool, then you may use `PyCharm IDE`. This has very good integration for those things(checkin/update/merge name it) that you mentioned from within the tool. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLwseyjzmdI) for more details.

PyCharm has also plugins `intellibot`, `RobotFramework` for getting context help while typing which increases the engineers productivity of writing the test more easily. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3Mg60r1Jjk) may help you to configure the tool.

Please note that the format of the tests would be `.robot` which the recommended.